# Star rating system save value on click only value save in database

Tags: jquery, mysql, rating

I'm trying to make a star rating system, i have this code and i want to make some changes on it, after the user clicks on the stars it shows an alert with how many stars and it resets the colors, what i want is the color filling to stay after the user clicks on it, and replace the alert with a div under the stars, here is my code:

**Js:**

```
$(function() {
    $("div.star-rating > s, div.star-rating-rtl > s").on("click", function(e) {

    // remove all active classes first, needed if user clicks multiple times
    $(this).closest('div').find('.active').removeClass('active');

    $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").addClass('active'); // all elements up from the clicked one excluding self
    $(e.target).addClass('active');  // the element user has clicked on


        var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").length+1;
        $('.show-result').text(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.show-result {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.star-rating s:hover,
.star-rating s.active {
    color: red;
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover,
.star-rating-rtl s.active {
    color: red;
}

.star-rating s,
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.star-rating {
    padding: 2px;
}
.star-rating-rtl {
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}
.star-rating-rtl s {
    color: yellow;
}
.star-rating s:hover:before,
.star-rating s.rated:before,
.star-rating s.active:before {
    content: "\2605";
}
.star-rating s:before {
    content: "\2606";
}
.star-rating-rtl s:hover:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.rated:after,
.star-rating-rtl s.active:after {
    content: "\2605";
}

.star-rating-rtl s:after {
    content: "\2606";
}
```

**html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
<div class="show-result">No stars selected yet.</div>
```

here value can display but how to store this value in mysql.

Comment: All that you need to do is post the numStars to a Server Side Script using AJAX and save it to the MySQL database.

Comment: i don't understand what you say please can u explain how

Comment: $('.show-result').text(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!")); here this can store increment values

Comment: ? where / how does it `store increment values` - it might update on the page at runtime but doesn't save the values

Comment: that one iam asking how to store the value in mysqli and display that value star fill though database

Answer (score 1):

To store the star ratings in database, you should use Ajax.
The code below shows using Jquery Ajax post to post values to a server side script (PHP).

```js
$(e.target).addClass('active');  // the element user has clicked on

var numStars = $(e.target).parentsUntil("div").length+1;
// modification starts here....
$.post( "saveRatings.php", { rating: numStars})// you may pass other necessary information 
     .done(function( data ) {
          $('.show-result').text(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));
});
```

on your `saveRatings.php` file,

```php
$ratings = $_POST['ratings'];
// You may need to pass more information to identify the user who gives the rating or the product that is being rated.

// Add your MySQL query to save the rating information to a database table

// return a success/failure response as needed.
```

> You may need to fetch the rating from the database and pass it to the javascript code to persist the ratings across page reloads.